# Show specific lines from a file using knitr/rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

### The problem

Let's say I have `script.R` that contains:

```
x <- data.frame(
    a = 1:10,
    b = 11:20
)

y <- rnorm(100)
```

I want to just show the first 4 lines that relate to `x`, in a chunk of an RMarkdown document.

---

### Things I've tried

- `{R, file = "script.R"}` as a knitr option will include the entire file, which I don't want
- `{R, code = xfun::read_all("script.R")[1:4]}` does let me subset the file, but it prints the result as an R vector with line numbers, rather than formatting it as source code
- The following hack *does* mostly work. It manually builds the markdown string. However, I find it very complex and messy, and I'm hoping for a better solution:

  ````
  ```{R, results="asis"}
  readLines("test.R")[1:4] |>
  c("```{r}", content=_, "```") |>
  paste(collapse = "\n") |>
  cat()
  ````
- Using `read_chunk`. This should work, but I dislike having to have two chunks when I only want one:

  ````
  ```{r, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
  knitr::read_chunk('script.R', labels="chunk-a", from=1, to=4)
  ```
  ```{r, chunk-a}
  ```
  ````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

````
```{r, code = readLines("test.R")[1:4]}
```
````

**Edit**

Or maybe this is cleaner:

````
```{r, code = readLines("test.R", n = 4)}
```
````

Comment: Yep. I actually had tried this, and it was in my question, but it seems that I did something wrong the first time. This works perfectly well.